# How can make this code run synchronous in Node.Js?

Tags: node.js, ftp-client

I Want to Move files using *EasyFTP*, but if i close the connection, it closes before moving any file, and if i don't close the connection i get an error.

**Error: 503 RNFR required first**

So here's my code

```
var EasyFtp = require('easy-ftp');
var ftp = new EasyFTP();
var config = {
    host: '',
    port: 21,
    username: '',
    password: ''
};

ftp.connect(config);

 var filesFrom=['/file1.txt','/anotherFile.txt','/moreFiles.txt','/a.txt','/x.txt']
 var filesTo=['/archived/file1.txt','/archived/anotherFile.txt','/archived/moreFiles.txt','/archived/a.txt','/archived/x.txt']

 for (var i = 0; i < filesFrom.length; i++) {
    ftp.mv(filesFrom[i], filesTo[i], function(err, newPath){
        if (err) { console.log(err) }
    });
 };

ftp.close();
```

Comment: You close the connection before you actually send the request, Use promises and Promise.all to close only when all the request finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make asynchronous things run synchronously in Javascript.  And, since a `for` loop is synchronous, you can't make a `for` loop wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before doing the next iteration.  So, instead, you have to use a different technique for your iteration.  There are many different options.  Here's one option that iterates manually, triggering the next iteration when the previous one is done:

```
function mvFiles(ftpObj, fromArray, toArray, callback) {
    let index = 0;
    let results = [];

    function next() {
        if (index < fromArray.length) {
            let i = index++;
            ftpObj.mv(fromArray[i], toArray[i], function(err, newPath) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    results[i] = newPath;
                    // run next iteration now
                    next();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // all done
            callback(null, results);
        }
    }

    // start first iteration
    next();
}
```

Usage:

```
ftp.connect(config);

var filesFrom =['/file1.txt','/anotherFile.txt','/moreFiles.txt','/a.txt','/x.txt'];
var filesTo =['/archived/file1.txt','/archived/anotherFile.txt','/archived/moreFiles.txt','/archived/a.txt','/archived/x.txt'];

mvFiles(ftp, filesFrom, filesTo, function(err, newPaths) {
    ftp.close();
    if (err) {
        // process error here
    } else {
        // all done here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with Bluebird

```
var Bluebird = require('Bluebird');
var EasyFtp = require('easy-ftp');
var ftp = new EasyFTP();
var config = {
    host: '',
    port: 21,
    username: '',
    password: ''
};

// Promisifying adds Async after every method which represents the promise version of that method... you don't have to follow the callback method.
Bluebird.promisifyAll(ftp);

ftp.connect(config);

// push your promises into an array and then Promise.all() it... It will either complete fully or throw an error even if one fails.... All or nothing.

var promises = [];

 var filesFrom=['/file1.txt','/anotherFile.txt','/moreFiles.txt','/a.txt','/x.txt']
 var filesTo=['/archived/file1.txt','/archived/anotherFile.txt','/archived/moreFiles.txt','/archived/a.txt','/archived/x.txt']

for (var i = 0; i < filesFrom.length; i++) {
    promises.push(ftp.mvAsync(filesFrom[i], filesTo[i]))
};

// Now promises array contains all the promises and they have started executing.

Bluebird.all(promises).then(function(results) {

     // Results is an array of results from all the promises in order.

     console.log(results);

     // Close connection.
     ftp.close();
}).catch(function(err) {
     console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: This code is running all the ftp operations in parallel at the same time.  Do you know for a fact that you can do that?  In Bluebird, you may as well use `Promise.map()` or `Promise.mapSeries()` rather than accumulate the promise array on your own. Saves a few lines of code and gives you concurrency control.